# Vue select - show list from specific option

Tags: vue.js, dropdown, selected

sI am making a Date selector of dropdowns. For a Year dropdown, I loop the options from 1900 to 2022. If I click on the dropdown it starts from 1990. But I want it to open from the middle of the list, let's say 1960 and scroll up or down.

```html
<div class="col-4 pr-0">
  <select v-model="dobYear" id="year" type="text" placeholder="Year">
    <option value="">Year</option>
    <option v-for="year in years" :value="year">[[ year ]]</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

`<option value="1970" selected>1970 </option>` does not work - just show this option on top.

**UPDATE**

if I initialize dobYear to 1960 it gives me:
[image]

but I need to be:

[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1LVH.png)

and then when I click on it dropdown opens and starts from 1960.

I added a function @click

```js
setToStartYear: function() {
  this.dobYear = 1960;
},
```

It kind of moves the list to 1960 but it won't let change the value of dobYear - stacks on 1960.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize related model `dobYear` to `1960`